# Why isn't the td text color changing

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a view with a table, and i am trying to set each text in the `td` to be a specific color. I am using Bootstrap but i dont see the changes I have made in my Site.css reflect in the view.

**View (html)**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "frmNumber", @class = "form-group"}))
    {
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="btnGetNumbers" title="Get Numbers"></button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1st Number</th>
                        <th>2nd Number</th>
                        <th>3rd Number</th>
                        <th>4th Numer</th>
                        <th>5th Number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        @if (null != Model)
                        {
                            <td class="firstNumber">@Model.Numbers[0]</td>
                            <td class="secondNumber">@Model.Numbers[1]</td>
                            <td class="thirdNumber">@Model.Numbers[2]</td>
                            <td class="fourthNumber">@Model.Numbers[3]</td>
                            <td class="fifthNumber">@Model.Numbers[4]</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.firstNumber {
    color: red;
}

.secondNumber {
    color: blue;
}

.thirdNumber {
    color: green;
}

.fourthNumber {
    color: orange;
}

.fifthNumber {
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: i checked your html and css.. it's working and I can see the td colors... it may have been over-ridden by bootstrap..

Comment: @severinolorillajr Thanks for your response, yes that was my guess, but my question is how to get it to work

Comment: i don't recommend this, but the easy fix would be to add `!important`. Some thing like this `color: red !important;` also try clearing your cache.

Comment: Remember that td cell's do NOT inherit properties of parent cells. Your code has to implicitly style each cell. Also the type of browser your using can have a big effect. I trust Chrome and Mozilla the most.

Comment: set your css selector more specific than bootstrap css selector . e.g add a Id to the table

Comment: I assume you have cleared your cache?

Comment: you can also go to dev console and check if it really overrides your css :)

Comment: I assume (but do not see them) that you have your opening and closing 'html' and 'body' tags.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell for certain from here but I'm thinking that you've overlooked the fact that you need to load your CSS *after* Bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

From what I checked, your code is working fine on JSFiddle. Perhaps to better diagnose what is overriding your CSS would be to check the rules using web inspector. From there you will be able to make changes to / rearrange the CSS stylesheets appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you should put your custom css AFTER your bootstrap CSS so the custom overrides any bootstrap styling (least that's how it usually works for myself) or, you could do it the messy way (!important, don't.)

So it'd be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
```

Comment: Come on! NEVER use !important!

Comment: "I don't advise doing it that way"

Comment: I know, sorry. I removed it.

Comment: You shouldn't offer it anyway. You don't know why the CSS is failing. For all you know there could be an !important flag somewhere else and this would just compound the problem.

Comment: @BradEvans it's okay. :p

Comment: If you don't advise something, you should never include it as advice.